# PowerShell wsl.exe access is denied

Tags: windows-10, powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to update WSL to WSL 2 on windows 10 but when I run any wsl command on powershell, I get ***access is denied*** error message. I am running powershell as admin still getting this error. Could not find any solution when googled this error for wsl.

[image]

Os version

[image]

Comment: WSL 2 is only available in Windows 10 builds 18917 or higher. Is this an Insider build?

Comment: Can you access WSL using the 'bash' command from Powershell?

Comment: Download procmon, start wsl and search in procmon for errors (tools - count value - Column: Result - Count). Procmon spews out tons of messages. Minimize the Start/Stop time.

Comment: Submit a screenshot of which Windows features you have installed

Comment: I repeat: you can't add WSL2 to Windows 10 build 17763. You need Build 18917 or higher, which at this time (January 2020) means using a Windows 10 Insider build.